# Multiple on conflict targets

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, duplication, upsert

I have two unique indexes on columns `a` and `b`. I need something like this:

```
insert into my_table (a, b) values (1, 2), (1, 2)
on conflict (a) do update set c = 'a_violation'
on conflict (b) do update set c = 'b_violation'
```

So generally I want to make different update based on conflict target - syntax above is not supported (only one `on conflict` statement is supported). Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered a trigger?

Comment: There are *many* ways. The best one depends on your undisclosed requirements. The outstanding virtue of `ON CONFLICT` is to handle race conditions under concurrent write load reliably ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Could you please elaborate on what any of these _many ways_ are?

Comment: @EliecerThoms: I didn't add an answer because the question is ambiguous in multiple ways. Depending on actual requirements, different answers apply. I elaborated now, mostly to illustrate why you wouldn't want to go there at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your example suggests duplicate rows in the `VALUES` clause itself - which would result in:

> ERROR:  ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time

Can be solved by folding duplicates in the input. See:

- [How to include excluded rows in RETURNING from INSERT … ON CONFLICT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35953488/939860)

But a related problem affects your outlined query as a whole, and that's not as easy to overcome.

What to do if the same input row triggers multiple unique violations?
What to do if multiple input rows trigger the same unique violation?
What to do if multiple input rows trigger distinct unique violations of the same target row?
And combinations thereof.

Postgres developers probably didn't want to open this can of worms and restricted the UPSERT feature to a *single* constraint.

[`ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) - without conflict target - works for *any* applicable violation. The alternative action for *this* variant ("do nothing") is unambiguous.

You would have to be a lot more specific (also about concurrency and possible write load) to get a more specific answer.